# Quartz.Net Create Schedule that triggers at multiple specific DateTimes

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I need to create a trigger that will fire at specific list of DateTimes.

I know that I can make a simple trigger for each `datetime`.

**My current code:**

```
var trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
                .ForJob(job)
                .WithCronSchedule(cron)                                   
                .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                .WithPriority(1)
                .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate your trigger with a Calendar and then choose the dates in the calendar on which you want the job to fire.

From documentation

> Quartz Calendar objects (not java.util.Calendar objects) can be
>   associated with triggers at the time the trigger is defined and stored
>   in the scheduler. Calendars are useful for excluding blocks of time
>   from the the trigger’s firing schedule. For instance, you could create
>   a trigger that fires a job every weekday at 9:30 am, but then add a
>   Calendar that excludes all of the business’s holidays.

Check more at the URL 
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04.html

Comment: I failed to find a proper example of Quartz Calendar with multiple specific dates. Could you be more specific how to do it?

Comment: I edited the answer and added the URL which you can check out. I think the URL is for Java. I expect the same in C#

Answer (score 0):

Using a StartAt on a WithCronSchedule won't work as I think you whant. the start at here is only to tell when the trigger should start using the cron.

Depending on your requirement, you may be able to create a cron specific to your need. For example :

```
0 0 5,10 * * ?
```

Will trigger every day at 5 and 10 AM.

Other than that, You're probably best to make one trigger per specific date, it will be much more flexible if you need to cancel on schedulled run. If you set all our trigger in the same trigger group, you will also be able to stom them all at once